# Conversion of Polygon vector files to Raster GRID 8 bit unsigned integer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, floating-point, bit-depth

I am trying to convert a polygon shapefile layer into Raster GRID with 8 bits and which is unsigned integer. I managed to convert the shapefile in ArcGIS with the Arc Toolbox Conversion tools, but the raster I get is GRID floating point 32 bits. I am trying to convert even that raster into GRID, have tried to use Copy Raster tool in Arc Toolbox as suggested by someone, but I didn't manage to get the right raster. It has a number of options there, I don't know which ones will do the work. THe options in Copy Raster are:

1. Convert 1 bit data into 8 bit optional
2. Colormap to RGB optional
3. Pixel Type: 8_BIT_UNSIGNED
4. Scale pixel value optional
5. RGB to colormap optional

I don't know whether to check 1,2,4 or not. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The pixel type will be based on the field you have chosen to use for your raster field (value field). If the values are right but populated as floating point then perhaps the Int tool resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000008z000000 might help. If you don't have spatial analyst then your best option is Gdal_Translate -ot byte http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html

Comment: I do have Spatial Analyst and I didn't know the Int would actually convert the bit-depth as well, which it did. Thanks Michael for the quick reply and all the help. :)